# Can Flatpak's apps installed in external drive and used on different Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, distributions, external-hdd, application, flatpak

I was thinking to create a workstation drive that contain all development apps and file and use it (plug & run) across many  device with different Linux distribution. Is that possible?

Comment: Looking at the [basic concepts](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/basic-concepts.html) page on flatpaks, you will need to provide the proper versions of all libraries used by the application. If REL 7 provides one version of `libz`, REL 8 a different version, and Ubuntu 22.04 yet a third version, you will need to have `libz` included in the flatpak. Repeat for all libraries needed by the app and by all the libraries needed by those libraries. The scenario is probably best solved using a Docker/Singularity container.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

However there are many caveats to that yes. If your app is written in a language that is interpreted liked Perl, Python, or Posix Shell Script then all you will need is to ensure every module your application depends on is also bundled with your app and that you do not use a construct that assumes any specific underlying platform i.e. assuming little endian integers. Then your app could run on any platform that has the interpreter on it. If your app is written and compiled into a bytecode that is meant to run on a virtual machine like Java then you be fine with the same constraints as a interpreted language app assuming java's write once run anywhere promise doesn't have any hidden gotcha's.

On the other hand programs compiled into machine executable binaries are much tricker to properly. It is still doable however there are pitfalls you will have to look out for and for mass release there are basically three ways you can do it.

The primary issue assuming all targets are of the same processor family can be broken down into three categories incompatible Kernel API, incompatible or incomplete userland ABI, and new processor opcodes.
The first is simple to understand the Linux Kernel has system calls added frequently and if your program tries to call a new system call on an older kernel that doesn't have that system call then your program wont work. The solution is choose an arbitrary target as your base line kernel and ensure that neither your app or the dependencies use newer system calls.
The third category is also relatively easy to understand. Newer processors in processor families will have opcodes that older versions will not interpret. These newer ops will be on the x86_64 platform things like AVX512 SIMD vector operations which can really speed up certain calculations but are relatively new. The solution is simple when you compile a program you can tell the compiler which version of the processor you which to specifically target and you just target an old generic one.

The second category is where things get tricky. This is because as a default programs are linked dynamically. Meaning when the binary file is generated it is incomplete. There isn't enough information on its own create a complete process image and an intermediate program must interpret the file to essentially complete the link when generating the process. The intermediate program is the dynamic linker and it is part of the systems C library. This leads to one issue that is somewhat in the weeds but important and that is the incompatible libc / dynamic linkers. If you build against glibc then your program might run using another libc but that isnt a guarantee. The dynamic binary will have somewhere a list of libraries that it depends on to run and might even have path information on where to find those libraries on your dev system but not the production system. This is a problem that can be solved one of three ways the first is the microsoft platform way of bundling applications with copies of each dependency. If your app includes in a non system directory then you can use a POSIX shell script to set the requisite path variables for the dynamic linker to find your bundled libraries instead of the system libraries. Look at the ld.so man page for more information. A second solution is to just statically link the app. This way you wont have to worry about any of the issues of dynamically linking. Finally the last solution I can think of for this problem is the let the users build it themselves solution which is only added for completeness and really isn't an answer. Leaving the options of bundling or statically linking. Both have merit however the former defeats one of the major points of dynamic linking which is to have one copy of a library in memory and so that an application can benefit from bug fixes in newer libraries. That being said the latter has issues when mixing code under different licenses so there are ups and downs to both.